# Problem with \maketitle in moderncv

Tags: errors, lyx, titles, moderncv

I downloaded the [`moderncv` template for LyX](http://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/CV#toc1), I tried to compile it but this error appears:

> \maketitle
>
> Your command was ignored.
>   Type  I    to replace it with another command,
>   or    to continue without it.

If I delete `\maketitle` it works, but the title, name and so don't appear!
I am not able to use LaTeX, I only use Lyx.
Please help me!

Comment: Where did you find the `moderncv` LyX template/layout file?

Comment: how can i change the picture from the example? i try for hours. thanks in advance!

Comment: @hanswurst If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I imported a moderncv lyx file to a new computer and "\maketitle" causes troubles. I've been using this lyx file for over 3 years.

Answer (score 2):

For me both `\maketitle` and `\makecvtitle` works fine. Have you set in the preamble something like this?:

```
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
% possible themes are "classic" and "casual"
% optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 
% 'red', 'green', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts,
% instead of sans serif fonts)
\firstname{Long John} % required
\familyname{\\Silver} % required
\title{Curriculum vitae} % optional 
\address{Treasure Island}{Pacific}% optional
\phone{555555555} % optional
\mobile{555555555}% optional
\fax{+43(0)999 7777} % optional
\email{ljsilver@treasureisland.com} % optional
\extrainfo{Pieces of Eight!} %optional
\photo[2 cm]{silverface} % optional
\quote{"Stand by to go about"} % optional
```

Comment: Yes I have I downloaded everything from the Lyx website. But it's with Lyx not with Latex. A friend of mine told me that maybe I should download some .sty files..do you know something of this?how do you do it?

Comment: In view complete source you can check the packages needed (lines with `\usepackage{something}`) but most probably you  have already these packages. LyX simply export your file to LaTeX to compile, so really is the same. Try to export to LaTeX (= copy the whole source in the viewer and save as a .tex file) and  then `pdflatex yourfile.tex` and the result must be the same PDF. Perhaps is better check that tex file with a text editor to find the problem.

Comment: If the code of the previous comment is your preamble in LyX, Disable  (put `%` before) or delete the line-s with `\pdfpageheight\paperheight \pdfpagewidth\paperwidth`, and **all** after the `\quote{...}` command. The `\maketitle` must be in the beginning of the body of the document (insert it in a ERT box with Ctrl+L) and not in the preamble.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the `\email` declaration. The document compiled after I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a problem in `Document->Settings->LaTex Preamble`, maybe in the address field.

if you see this:
`\address{Teststreet 17}{03333 Nicecity \\  Switzerland}`

try changing it to 
`\address{Teststreet 17}{03333 Nicecity}{  Switzerland}`

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but I found the solution.

In my case, I had `\\` in some fields, for example :

```
\title{
    Administrateur système GNU--Linux \\ Responsable technique.
   }
```

When I deleted `\\`, the compilation ran correctly.

```
\title{
    Administrateur système GNU--Linux Responsable technique.
   }
```

If there is a `\\` string in the fields `firstname`, `familyname`, `title`, `address`, etc..., the problem appears.